# How can I copy a specific word from a text file using Batch script?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a json/text file. I need extract specific words from json/text file. There are so many vin numbers, stock numbers and so on.Anyone can help me please with a complete batch script? File like:

```
Regular","horsepower":265,"horsepowerRpm":6200,"engineSize":"3.5L","engineTorque":245,"engineTorqueRpm":4700,"priorUses":[],"comingSoonDate":null,{"stockNumber":18077069,"vin":"JTHBL46F785055089","year":2008,"make":"Lexus","model":"LS 460","body":"4D Sedan","trim":"","basePrice":14998.0,"msrp":61500.0,"mileage":89056,"storeId":6072,"storeName":"Capitol Expressway","storeCity":"San Jose","geoCity":"San Jose","state":"California","stateAbbreviation":null,"
"engineTorqueRpm":null,"priorUses":["10","30"],"comingSoonDate":null},{"stockNumber":18077755,"vin":"JTDKDTB35D1042055","year":2013,"make":"Toyota","model":"Prius c","body":"4D Hatchback","trim":"Three","basePrice":11599.0,"msrp":19100.0,"mileage":100787,"storeId":6072,"storeName":"Capitol Expressway","storeCity":"San Jose","geoCity":"San Jose","state":"California","stateAbbreviation":null,"averageRating":4.
```

Need extract required word. Like [The marked position I need to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ32C.png)

And output store into a CSV file.
[Output should be like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSjx2.png)

Thanks

Comment: Hi Guys, Anyone can solve this?